# Azure data factory ingest csv with full stop in header

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

I have a copy data activity in Azure data factory which reads in a csv file. This csv file is produced by a 3rd party so I cannot change it. One of the headings has a full stop (or period) in it: 'foo.bar'. When I run the activity I get the error message:

```
Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file 'foo;bar'.
Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,'
```

The csv look like this

```
state,sys_updated_on,foo.bar,sys_id
New,03/06/2021 12:42:18,S Services,xxx
Resolved,03/06/2021 12:35:06,MS Services,yyy
New,03/06/2021 12:46:18,S Services,zzz
```

The source dataset looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "my_dataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "my_linked_service",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": "i.csv",
                "folderPath": "Temp/exports/widgets",
                "container": "blah"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show use some piece of your csv data.

Comment: I have updated the question with some csv data @LeonYue

Comment: Hi @Tino, please see my answer, please correct me if I misunderstand the problem.

Comment: @LeonYue I can't skip the header as I need predictable headings in a subsequent python script. I will look at the derived column approach you suggest

Comment: so you really purpose is convert the csv to json? Just according the error message, it seams that you are using the JSON format to parse the csv data.

Comment: yes the sink is json format

Comment: Then I'm afraid to say we can't achieve that since you can't change the header/key.

Comment: Hi @Tino, that's the limit of JSON key name rule. Do  you have any other concerns?

Comment: To be clear I can change the column name from foo.bar in the csv to foo_bar in the json so I explored data flows. The problem I now have is that the datafactory platform (which is not ours) will only allow me to use the self-hosted integration runtime which seems to rule out data flows.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the header like this:

1. Don't set first row as header:
   [image]
2. Set Skip line count: 1 at source settings:
   [image]

Some other way, you also could use Data Flow with [Derived column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to create a new schema to replace the column `foo.bar`:
[image]